# Convert boost ptime from GMT to UTC

Tags: datetime, boost, timezone, utc, gmt

I am trying to convert `boost::posix_time::ptime` from GMT to UTC.
I went on Boost web site, and most of the examples are for US time zone, but I need the GMT one.

All I need is the right parameters to put in `boost::date_time::local_adjustor`

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: By GMT you mean WET (Western European Time)?

Comment: No I mean GMT (Greenwich Mean Time), which must be WET-1hour

Comment: Ok, I am confused: according to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time) WET is the same as GMT, and WEST (the summer time) is of course GMT+1.

Comment: You are right GMT and WEST are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming this is WET your string should be (Summertime is from last Sunday in April, 2:00 until last Sunday in October, 3:00):

```
"WET-0WEST,M4.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00"
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to use this string with the local_adjustor ? thank you.

Comment: I've found this very convenient web page: http://code.google.com/p/x-wrt/source/browse/trunk/package/webif/files/usr/lib/webif/timezones.csv?r=2936